# Remove pattern from xml with python etree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, recursion

I have a xml file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kw name="k1" library="k1">
    <kw name="k2" library="k2">
        <kw name="Keep This" library="Keep This">
            <c name="c4" library="c4">
            </c>
        </kw>
        <kw name="k3" library="k3">
            <c name="c4" library="c4">
            </c>
        </kw>
        <c name="c3" library="c3">
            <c name="c4" library="c4">
            </c>
        </c>
    </kw>
</kw>
```

And I want to remove the table **but except** fulfill following rule:

1. **tag** = *kw*  and  **attribute** contains *"Keep This"*
2. Those tags is not kw

The other table should be remove from xml

So the output should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kw name="k1" library="k1">
    <kw name="k2" library="k2">
        <kw name="Keep This" library="Keep This">
            <c name="c4" library="c4">
            </c>
        </kw>
        <c name="c3" library="c3">
            <c name="c4" library="c4">
            </c>
        </c>
    </kw>
</kw>
```

It's really hard to trace recursive function, does anyone can help me or recommend another way to achieve my requirements?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


def check(root):
    # if subchild exist "kw" tag, parse to the subchild
    if 'kw' in ([child.tag for child in root]):
        for child in root:
            flag = check(child)
            # remove
            if not flag:
                root.remove(child)
    # if subchild dose not exist "kw" tag
    else:
        if root.tag == 'kw':
            # Check if itself's tag is kw and "Keep this"
            if 'Keep This' in [root.attrib[child] for child in root.attrib]:
                return True
            # Remove if itself's tag is kw but without "Keep this"
            else:
                print ('remove')
                return False
        else:
            return True

check(root)

ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: Since you want to map xml to xml this is really a job for xslt.

Comment: Consider XSLT with Identity Transform and one-line template. See [demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2D1). Python can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with `lxml` or [external processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following recursive function instead. Note the use of an exception as a way to notify the parent to remove the child, since node removal has to be done from the parent and the Boolean return value only indicates whether or not a descendant with tag of `kw` and an attribute value of `Keep This` is found. This has the benefit of notifying the caller when there is no "keep" node found at all under the root node, which, according to the rule, should be removed, but cannot be because it is the root node:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def check(node):
    if node.tag == 'kw' and any(value == 'Keep This' for value in node.attrib.values()):
        return True
    keep = False
    removals = []
    for child in node:
        try:
            if check(child):
                keep = True
        except RuntimeError:
            removals.append(child)
    for child in removals:
        node.remove(child)
    if node.tag == 'kw' and not keep:
        raise RuntimeError('No "keep" node found under this node')
    return keep

tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
check(root)
ET.dump(root)
```

With your sample input, this outputs:

```
<kw library="k1" name="k1">
    <kw library="k2" name="k2">
        <kw library="Keep This" name="Keep This">
            <c library="c4" name="c4">
            </c>
        </kw>
        <c library="c3" name="c3">
            <c library="c4" name="c4">
            </c>
        </c>
    </kw>
</kw>
```

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this, your answer is perfect for this input, but if it has second <kw> without "Keep This "in the same layer, it will not be remove.
I think it's because remove() will break the original structure, then this for loop will be impact by this remove action. So it will not travel all node in this layer.

Comment: Good call. I've fixed it by postponing the removals until the processing of all children is done.